# Rails app folder is large due to GIT pack file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, github

So I noticed that my Heroku slug size was huge (100mb) and decided to inspect my Rails project structure to see what was causing the huge size.

When I inspected the project folder it said that it was approx 100mb in size. However, after inspecting all the (first level) children files and folders I couldn't see any culprit (my logs are deleted on a daily basis).

I tried deleting the entire contents (code is up on github of course!) but when I inspect the folder it still says its 99.9mb on disk - weird.

I sudo'd into the folder in terminal and ran ls -al to see if there were any hidden files or folders but only got the following:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 <name>  staff  15364 15 Apr 16:03 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x   3 <name>  staff    102 17 Apr  2012 .bundle
drwxr-xr-x  18 <name>  staff    612 15 Apr 15:18 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 <name>  staff    487  4 Apr 10:21 .gitignore
```

Nothing unusual there I think.

Has anyone seen a similar situation and can advise a solution?

**UPDATE**

So it looks as though the .pack file(s) in the .git folder are the issue here. I did a little searching and ran

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch unwanted_folder' --prune-empty
```

and

```
git gc --aggressive --prune
```

Which removed all but one of the pack files. Whats confusing me is why the remaining pack file is 75mb when all code and assets come to 25mb? I'm guessing its keeping a history of the changes made locally since the repo was initialised or something? If so, how do I clear these down? I store all changes on github anyway so the old files/versions are redundant (unless I'm missing something?).

Comment: Run `du -h` on your git project directory.

Comment: To get sorted results, `du | sort -n`.

Comment: What use will this do if the directory is empty (barring the files listed above)?

Comment: It should show you file sizes recursively, not just the size of the folder node, which ls does.

Comment: Surprised this question isn't voted up more than it is.